# SOLR daterange with no or infinite end_date

Tags: search, solr, date-range

I'm new to SOLR and I have an issue with a query for a daterange with no end_date. For non-null end_date it works fine.
However, I want to get all users who have come today or earlier and who don't have the end_date or (start_date = end_date).
But I don't obtain any expected users. Will appreciate any help.

Tried to use type="string" and type="date".

My schema:

`<field name="startDate" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="true" />`

`<field name="endDate" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="true" />`

My query is:
`?q=startDate:[* TO NOW] AND endDate:[NOW TO *]`

Also tried:
`?q=startDate:[* TO NOW] AND endDate:[NOW TO *:*]`

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is the answer you are looking for:

q

```
start_date:[* TO NOW] AND (end_date:[NOW TO *] OR  (*:* NOT end_date:*) )
```